# Expressing Basis Vectors in Polar Coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry

Consider the polar coordinate transformation

$$
x = r\cos \theta 
$$
$$
y = r\sin \theta
$$

I am trying to find the most direct way to compute the coordinate basis vectors

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial}{\partial y}
$$

The exterior derivatives of $x$ and $y$ are given by

$$
dx = \cos \theta dr - r\sin\theta d\theta
$$
$$
dy = \sin \theta dr + r \cos \theta d\theta
$$
Considering that $dx$ and $dy$ comprise a basis in the cotangent space dual to the tangent space with basis elements $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$, in principle, one ought to be able to compute the latter by using the duality relations
$$
dx \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right) = 1, dx \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right) = 0, dy \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right) = 1, dy \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right) = 0
$$

Unfortunately, I am unable to make the algebra for this work out as expected. Is this approach promising, and perhaps I'm simply missing some algebraic manipulations or is there a better approach to this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is promising. Write 
$$
  \frac{\partial}{\partial x} = a_{xr} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} + a_{x \theta} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \qquad 
   \frac{\partial}{\partial y} = a_{yr} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} + a_{y \theta} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} 
$$
Now
$$
  \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} = 
   \begin{pmatrix} \langle \mathrm{d} x, \frac{\partial}{\partial x}  \rangle & \langle \mathrm{d} y, \frac{\partial}{\partial x}  \rangle \\ 
   \langle \mathrm{d} x, \frac{\partial}{\partial y}  \rangle & \langle \mathrm{d} y, \frac{\partial}{\partial y}  \rangle \end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
    \cos\theta & \sin \theta \\
    -r \sin\theta & r \cos \theta
\end{pmatrix} \cdot 
\begin{pmatrix} \langle \mathrm{d} r, \frac{\partial}{\partial r}  \rangle & \langle \mathrm{d} \theta, \frac{\partial}{\partial r}  \rangle \\ 
   \langle \mathrm{d} r, \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}  \rangle & \langle \mathrm{d} \theta, \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}  \rangle \end{pmatrix} \cdot
  \begin{pmatrix} 
       a_{x r} & a_{x \theta} \\ a_{y r} & a_{y \theta}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Thus
$$
   \begin{pmatrix} 
       a_{x r} & a_{x \theta} \\ a_{y r} & a_{y \theta}
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 
    \cos\theta & \sin \theta \\
    -r \sin\theta & r \cos \theta
\end{pmatrix}^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} 
    \cos\theta & -\frac{1}{r}\sin \theta \\
    \sin\theta & \frac{1}{r}  \cos \theta
\end{pmatrix} 
$$
Thus
$$
   \frac{\partial}{\partial x} = \cos(\theta) \frac{\partial}{\partial r} - \sin(\theta) \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \qquad
   \frac{\partial}{\partial y} = \sin(\theta) \frac{\partial}{\partial r} + \cos(\theta) \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} 
$$

Comment: Nice! I can see where I went wrong now.

Comment: I see it works, but what is exactly the operation represented by $\begin{pmatrix} 
    \cos\theta & \sin \theta \\
    -r \sin\theta & r \cos \theta
\end{pmatrix} \cdot 
\begin{pmatrix} \langle \mathrm{d} r, \frac{\partial}{\partial r}  \rangle & \langle \mathrm{d} \theta, \frac{\partial}{\partial r}  \rangle \\ 
   \langle \mathrm{d} r, \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}  \rangle & \langle \mathrm{d} \theta, \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}  \rangle \end{pmatrix} \cdot
  \begin{pmatrix} 
       a_{x r} & a_{x \theta} \\ a_{y r} & a_{y \theta}
\end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: The matrix in the middle is the identity. Is it there just symbolically? Clearly it is ignored when solving with the inverse of the matrix of trig functions...

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use the chain rule:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}+\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}$$
and similarly for $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$.

Your method should also work, however; can you show us what went wrong?

Comment: But this would imply, would it not, that one would have to apply the inverse function theorem to obtain the partials of $r$ and $\theta$? I can see how this would probably work, but I'm hoping for something that doesn't require as much technology; maybe I can't get there without it though..

Comment: In general you would use the inverse function theorem, but in this case the inverse functions are easy to find explicitly: $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $\theta=\arctan(y/x)$.

Answer (score 1):

using $x=r\cos\theta, y=r\sin\theta, r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}, \theta=\arctan(y/x)$ we have
$$
\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}=\cos\theta, \frac{\partial r}{\partial y}=\sin\theta, \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}=-\frac{\sin\theta}{r},\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial y}=\frac{\cos\theta}{r}
$$
then using the chain rule
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}+\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}=\cos\theta\frac{\partial}{\partial r}-\frac{\sin\theta}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}
$$
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial r}{\partial y}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}+\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial y}\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}=\sin\theta\frac{\partial}{\partial r}+\frac{\cos\theta}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}
$$