# Matrix expression in polar coordinate basis vector

Tags: differential-geometry

I see two ways of obtaining the desired result: either as in [this answer (although not exactly the same)](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3740422/994433) with a linear system (matrices) as in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/97959/994433):

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} = 
   \begin{pmatrix} \langle \mathrm{d} x, \frac{\partial}{\partial x}  \rangle & \langle \mathrm{d} y, \frac{\partial}{\partial x}  \rangle \\ 
   \langle \mathrm{d} x, \frac{\partial}{\partial y}  \rangle & \langle \mathrm{d} y, \frac{\partial}{\partial y}  \rangle \end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
    \cos\theta & \sin \theta \\
    -r \sin\theta & r \cos \theta
\end{pmatrix} \cdot 
\begin{pmatrix} \langle \mathrm{d} r, \frac{\partial}{\partial r}  \rangle & \langle \mathrm{d} \theta, \frac{\partial}{\partial r}  \rangle \\ 
   \langle \mathrm{d} r, \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}  \rangle & \langle \mathrm{d} \theta, \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}  \rangle \end{pmatrix} \cdot
  \begin{pmatrix} 
       a_{x r} & a_{x \theta} \\ a_{y r} & a_{y \theta}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

The question is what is the purpose or meaning of the middle matrix in the very last part of the above expression (the scalar products of basis covectors and basis vectors)? Shouldn't it be the the identity matrix by definition (Kronecker delta)?

Comment: THe middle matrix is indeed the identity, but what are you trying to compute here? Please make your question self-contained rather than linking to two separate questions.

Comment: @peek-a-boo The computation is clear from the expression, and solved in the linked answer: The final objective (second matrix above) is the basis vectors $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i},$ but the question is why there is that middle matrix included in the answer linked.

Comment: I don't know... it is indeed the identity matrix.  The fact that the two matrices are inverse to each other follows from the chain rule. Perhaps they had a specific way of thinking about change of coordinates, which led them to putting the matrix there, but I can't read their mind.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thank you. Happy to see I'm not missing out on something big.